# DataGrid , TextBox - binding and instant updates

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

My app. contains the window in the picture:

[image]

The ItemsSource of the DataGrid is set to _editList ( **declared as  IList < Vendor > _editList;**).

The data grid is set to **Read Only**.

The Vendor Name text box has the binding set as : 
    **Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGridVendors, Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"**

This works well. However, as it is the Vendor Name cell only updates when the user is done typing in the Vendor Name textbox and clicks on something else. Say I want to change the vendor name to "John Lennon II" . I have to click on the textbox and type the characters I want to add and than I have to click on something else and only then the datagrid makes the update.

I want to make the update happen as the user types the characters....Is this possible ?

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the UpdateSourceTrigger to your Binding

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGridVendors, Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Its default trigger is lost focus. When you change it to PropertyChanged the Updates will done when you're typing.